# Kendo dataviz pan and zoom

Tags: json, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I have a chart which binds to large data, so is there anyway to show only the first few items and the remaining items should be viewed only by zooming

my json looks like this

```
[
  {
    item:name1,
    count:200
  },
  {
    item:name2,
    count:100
  },
  {
    item:name3,
    count:5000
  },
  {
    item:name4,
    count:500
  }
]
```

The category axis is 'item' field and the y axis is the count field
I am using KendoChart and my requirement is to only show the first two items initially and the remaining two must be shown only by either draging or zooming.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you found this already by now, but I think you're [looking for this](http://demos.kendoui.com/dataviz/bar-charts/pan-and-zoom.html)... the demo appears to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.